# How to create ROI in Semi-Automatic Classification plugin QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, classification

while trying to classify landsat images, I get the following problem:

I click on the pixel I want to define a ROI, but the ROI polygon that the plugin creates appears in a different part of the image instead of appearing over the selected pixel...
The pink arrow shows the pixel I clicked to create the ROI and the blue arrow shows the ROI polygon that appears. Does anyone know how to fix this?
[image]

- It was a projection problem: I projected the images to it's original projection and after reclassifying the image I changed the projection.

Comment: Wow, that's bad! What spatial reference is your project in? Is it the same as the raster?

Comment: There was a problem with the projection...

Comment: I suspected as much, perhaps you could answer your own question detailing what the problem was and how you rectified it... no doubt someone in the future will encounter the same situation.